# Windows 10 Reboot Sticks on Manufacturer Logo Screen, Shutdown works fine

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, reboot

So, this started happening a long time ago, after some windows update I believe, but I cannot figure it out.

Basically when I restart windows, either through an interface (windows directly, updates, etc.), or CLI (shutdown -r ...), it hangs on the manufacturer logo after it comes back on.

[image]

I can hard power it off and power it on, and it goes back to the windows bootup process, but using restart, it always hangs, and hangs forever, it will not continue without powering it off.

Functionally this hasn't been a problem because in the case of things like updates they pick back up when I power it back on, but I can't find anywhere in Windows or BIOS settings that might cause this, I haven't in 20 some years of working with Windows seen this before. Nothing I can find in windows or bios logs indicate a problem.

Has anyone ever experienced this or know of anything that would cause a hang on the manufacturer logo, prior to getting to the windows bootup process?

To add, I have done SFC scannow and other standard diagnostics on the OS, hardware, and hard drives, all are functioning properly, this persisted past a hard drive replacement as well.

Comment: Hardware OK and problem persists past HDD replacement……..  Is there perhaps an issue with your Windows image? Can you try vanilla Windows?  Can you update BIOS, Chipset, and all other drivers?

Comment: The biggest difference is that with hybrid shutdown, the system does not actually boot between being off and on, and as such drivers are not initialized, but restored from hibernation. My suggestion therefor would be to update all drivers and see if that fixes it.